# Is there a way to have unit test file at the same path of tested file in a Swift Package?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, package, swift-package-manager

I want to have my unit test file at the same path of the tested file.

Using SPM I couldn't make it work. To make it clearer I want something like this:

```
Sources
 -- MyPackage
 ----- MyCode.swift
 ----- MyCodeTests.swift
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift Package Manager is not designed for this kind of directory structure. Your tests and sources are in different targets, which are most easily declared by specifying a directory containing all the sources for that target.

While it is technically possible to do this, it is not practical. You would need to list all the source files for your package, and the unit tests, separately, as the files for different targets cannot overlap.

This means that you would need to edit Package.swift every time you add/remove/rename a file.

Here is an example:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "MyPackage",
            sources: ["MyCode.swift", /* every other source file */]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"],
            path: "Sources/MyPackage",
            sources: ["MyCodeTests.swift", /* every other test file */]
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Like you said, it is not practical. I really like that structure because you don't have to build a new structure (folders) only for unit tests. You can also quickly see unit tests associated with the implementation (same path), also see if an implementation have its unit tests file... I see lots of advantages and comfort using that structre. But I don't know if it worth when I see how painful it is in a SPM..

Comment: @tisma An idea just came to mind - since Package.swift is just Swift code, you can `import Foundation` and use `FileManager` to find all the files that end with `Tests.swift` and the files that don't. Not sure how well this would work though.

Comment: You mean doing a sort of Swift script inside the `Package.swift`?

Comment: @tisma Yes. You can assign to `package.targets[1].sources`. But apparently `FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath` is the root directory when opening the package in Xcode, so I'm not sure how you would find the directory in which the package resides.